# need your assistance to run the redux app

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, require

Please help me to solve the error what I am facing when it's running the code ..

Unable to solve this problem.. tried out my best..

I've also added `import` to import the required elements. I'm just learning on the other platform.. just got stuck after  getting some errors even tried out.

I've just mentioned as same as I have got it from StackBlitz.. Why I'm facing this error..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>Page Title</title>

          <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin>

        </script>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script> 

    </head>

    <body>

      <div id="root"></div>

      <script type="text/babel">

      import React from 'react';

      import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

      import {createStore} from 'redux';

      import {connect} from 'react-redux';

      

          function incrementCounter(num) {

              return {

                  type: 'INCREMENT',

                  num: num

              }

            }

          const initialState  = {

              count: 0

          };

          

          function reducer(state= initialState, action) {

              switch(action.type) {

                case 'INCREMENT': 

                  return { count: state.count + action.num  }

                default:

                  return state

           }

          

          }

          

          let counter = (props) => {

              function handleClick() {

                  props.incrementCounter(1);

              }

              

              return 

                  <div>

                    <p>{props.count}</p>

                    <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment</button>

                  </div>;

          }

          

          function mapStateToProps(state) {

              return {

                  count: state.count

              };

          }

          

          const mapDispatchToProps = {

              incrementCounter 

          }

          

           let store = createStore(reducer);

          

           Counter = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);

          

          ReactDOM.render(

             <Provider store={store}>

              <Counter/>

             </Provider>,

            document.getElementById("root")

          );

      </script>

    </body>
```

error showing similar to the image below:

[image: error]

Answer (score -1):

If you followed some kind of tutorial to get to this point, there is likely something missing or you skipped a step. I'd recommend to try out a starter kit like "create-react-app" and once you have that up and running, try to add redux manually.